# How do you get Visual Studio Test Explorer to show React Typescript tests?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, visual-studio-2022

I've done Run All, that doesn't find them.  At command line I can run npm test and it finds and executes the tests.  However, they never show in Test Explorer.  I created the React Typescript project from the 2022 template.

I expected to see my name.Test.tsx tests in Test Explorer.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/unit-testing-javascript-with-visual-studio

Comment: No, I've already looked at that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but make sure you've installed `jest-editor-support` in your npm dev dependencies (e.g. `npm i -D jest-editor-support`)